# Using A Language Server To Find All Functions Within a scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode extension and for one of the key features, I need to go to the main scope (the code this works with is C) and recursively find a certain method. So if I pass in `foo`, it should return `main calls foo` or `main calls bar calls foo` and all other places where foo is called. I've looked through the VSCode language server protocol but it's all high-level things and I can't do things like getting the methods called in a specific scope. Does anyone know how to do this or have any resources to help me figure this out?

Comment: That sounds a bit like call hierarchy? https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#callHierarchy_incomingCalls